# Loading records into dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, getline

I'm trying to load a number of records from a textfile into a dynamic array.

The records are separated by commas

eg: lost,cat,female,persian,0 3,black

This is what i have so far:

```
struct Pet{

      char status[6];
      char petType[4];
      ...
}

void loadRecords(char * filename, Pet * petPointer, int count){

      ifstream fin;
      Pet* petPointer = new Pet[count];

      fin.open(filename); 

      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
           while (fin.good())
           {
                getline(fin, petPointer->status[i], ',');
                ...
           }
      }
}
```

This is returning the error "no instance of overloaded function “getline” matches argument list"

What would be the best way to load these records into an array?

Comment: Use `#include <iostream>` and prefix with `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your string as a an array, and your array as a pointer. Which is valid, because strings are arrays and arrays are pointers, but it is not what your want.
You should be doing this:

```
getline(fin, petPointer[i].status,  ',');
```

It's a littlebit confusing to call your array a pointer (`petPoitner`). It is a pointer, since it is an array, but you intend to use it as an array.

If you want to use a pointer in the cool `c` way of doing things, you can do:

```
Pet* pets = new Pet[count];
Pet* iter = pets;

while(...){
    getline(fin, iter->status);
    iter++;
}
```

Either way, in both ways you probably still should check for inserting more than you reserve memory for.